# write a list to Excel, starting at a specific cell, with openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to write a list of values to an Excel spreadsheet, starting at a specific cell.  The values will be written periodically and the new values will replace the existing values, so writing will always start in cell F2.  I have tried multiple versions that I found on SO and other sites but I keep getting various errors, most recently a KeyError = 0 for these efforts :

```
for rowNum in range(len(list)):
    ws.cell(row=rowNum+1, column=5).value = list[rowNum]

for i in range(len(list)):
    ws['F' + r].value = list[i+1]
```

PLEASE help !  Many thanks in advance.

Edit - I found the solution in "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python", chapter 12.  I converted my dataframe to a dictionary and then this worked :

```
for rowNum in range(2, ws.max_row):
    item = ws.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
    if item in new_dict:
        ws.cell(row=rowNum, column=5).value = new_dict[item]
```

Comment: Please post the full source of the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the script below and it worked fine for me.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("C:\\Users\\your_path_here\\Desktop\\sample.xlsx")
```